# Dropbox API: How to use API to get file's shared link?

Tags: dropbox-api

I have a folder which contains 100+ files. I want to share them all and get all the shared links. Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) endpoint to get [shareable links](https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en) to any file or folder.

Answer (score 9):

That's DropBox API v. 1, which is now deprecated:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/

I found, for current v.2, depending on your needs:

`/2/files/get_temporary_link` https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link

`/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings` https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

`/2/sharing/create_shared_link` https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link

Comment: I have also discovered that create_shared_link will return an "Error" "SharedLinkAlreadyExists" for a valid already-shared path, but will still return the ShareData object regardless.

Comment: `create_shared_link` is already deprecated. Instead use `2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings` to create share links and `2/sharing/list_shared_links` to get their list (for a given file).